# Using webpack for bundeling vs code extention code returns into error

Tags: typescript, webpack, vscode-extensions

When I try to import a library I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at maxGraphLogic.js:2:23`

I think it is due to a wrong configuration of Webpack, because I already did these steps from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/browser-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined). I have also created a dummy website without using Webpack. The import worked there.

The webpack.config is boilerplate:

webpack.config.ts

```
const path = require('path');

//@ts-check
/** @typedef {import('webpack').Configuration} WebpackConfig **/

/** @type WebpackConfig */
const extensionConfig = {
  target: 'node', // VS Code extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/
    mode: 'none', // this leaves the source code as close as possible to the original (when packaging we set this to 'production')

  entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  output: {
    // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'extension.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    // modules added here also need to be added in the .vscodeignore file
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  infrastructureLogging: {
    level: "log", // enables logging required for problem matchers
  },
};
module.exports = [ extensionConfig ];
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "Node16",
        "target": "ES2022",
        "lib": [
            "ES2022",
            "dom"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true   /* enable all strict type-checking options */
        /* Additional Checks */
        // "noImplicitReturns": true, /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true, /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    }
}
```

maxGraphLogic.ts. Compiled to .js before usage ofc:

```
import { type CellStyle, Graph, InternalEvent } from '@maxgraph/core';

function loadGraphContainer(){
    const container = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('graphContainer');
    // Disables the built-in context menu
    InternalEvent.disableContextMenu(container);

    const graph = new Graph(container);
    graph.setPanning(true); // Use mouse right button for panning
    // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
    // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
    const parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

    // Adds cells to the model in a single step
    graph.batchUpdate(() => {
        const vertex01 = graph.insertVertex({
            parent,
            position: [10, 10],
            size: [100, 100],
            value: 'rectangle',
        });
        const vertex02 = graph.insertVertex({
            parent,
            position: [350, 90],
            size: [50, 50],
            style: {
                fillColor: 'orange',
                shape: 'ellipse',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                verticalLabelPosition: 'bottom',
            },
            value: 'ellipse',
        });
        graph.insertEdge({
            parent,
            source: vertex01,
            target: vertex02,
            value: 'edge',
            style: {
                edgeStyle: 'orthogonalEdgeStyle',
                rounded: true,
            },
        });
    });

}
loadGraphContainer();
```

Used here at getWebviewContent:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import * as path from 'path';

export class MaxGraphPanel {
  //...
 
    
    public getWebviewContent(value: String) {
        const scriptPathOnDisk = vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extentionUri, 'src', 'maxGraphLogic.js');
        // And the uri we use to load this script in the webview
        const scriptUri = this.panel.webview.asWebviewUri(scriptPathOnDisk);
        console.log(scriptUri);
       
        return `<html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>mxGraph VSCode Extension Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="graphContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
          
          <script type="module" src=${scriptUri}></script>
          </body>
        
      
        </html>`;
      }
  //...

}
```